# Irregular writing to XML with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, merge, linq-to-xml

I've been working on storing data in XML, but I use a level system to allow users to access some data and not other. But this happens in different cycles and data is read and written to irregular. This gives me the following error:

> Additional information: This operation would create an incorrectly
>   structured document.

At:

```
doc.Add(new XElement(UserLevel, new XElement(CommandName.Remove(0, 1), CommandInfo)));
```

This is the complete function:

```
private bool SetCommands(string CommandName, string CommandInfo, string UserLevel)
{
    if (GetCommand(CommandName) == "none")
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();

        if (File.Exists(XmlFileLocation))
            doc = XDocument.Load(XmlFileLocation);

        doc.Add(new XElement(UserLevel, new XElement(CommandName.Remove(0, 1), CommandInfo)));
        doc.Save(XmlFileLocation);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to write to the file under the same UserLevel with different CommandNames which then hold different CommandInfos. Later on I plan to be able to edit the CommandInfo, so I'll have to overwrite what has been written.

What am I looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML document can only have one root element, and you seem to be trying to add more than one. Just create a top level element, say `Users`, and add the `UserLevel`'s as its children.

Something like this:

```
private bool SetCommands(string CommandName, string CommandInfo, string UserLevel)
{
    if (GetCommand(CommandName) == "none")
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();

        if (File.Exists(XmlFileLocation))
            doc = XDocument.Load(XmlFileLocation);

        var users = doc.Root.Element("Users");
        if (users == null)
        {
            users = new XElement("Users");
            doc.Add(users);
        }

        users.Add(new XElement(UserLevel, new XElement(CommandName.Remove(0, 1), CommandInfo)));
        doc.Save(XmlFileLocation);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, and thanks for the suggestion, but continuously saving gave the same error. But not at the same place. It gets it now when it wants to execute `doc.save(XMLFileLocation);`. Any suggestions?